# Using installed pip packages in a newer release of Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Because of the size of the installed `pip` packages , I moved the `~/.local/lib/python3.6` directory to another partition and then made a symlink(a.k.a shortcut for windows users) to it , and that had been worked fine.
But recently I installed a newer linux distribution which has `python3.8` pre-installed and I want to re-use those `python3.6` packages(since the minor version is the same) to obviate the need of re-installing them.(almost 3.5 GB)

I made a symlink (`~/.local/lib/python3.8/` which is the exact name that pip creates itself) to `/path/to/external/lib/python3.6` , but now python shell is unable to recognize those packages.

Any ideas?
Do I need to re-install them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These projects have to be reinstalled. There is no compatibility guarantee between minor versions (or major obviously), only between maintenance versions.